# Error querying Parse users on Parse.Cloud.beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

I am receiving this error:
Error: success/error was not called.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong in the code?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Chat", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query('_User');
    query.equalTo("mode", 1);
    query.find({
        succes:function(results){
            if (results.length > 0) {
                response.success();
            } else {
                response.error("No users available");
            }
        },
        error:function() {
            response.error("Query error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success callback was named incorrectly, so it wasn't firing, but you may also have an issue with security and should use the master key in cloud code to override it.  Try this, with promises:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Chat", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("mode", 1);
    query.limit(1);
    query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results){
      if (results.length) {
         response.success();
      } else {
         response.error("No users available");
      }
    },function(error) {
      response.error("Query error");
    });
});
```